# naming convention for a Nullable boolean toggle

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a message entity say (`Message`) which can be configured by the creator as

1. `IsWebOnly` where by it will be shown only on regular website
2. `IsMobileOnly` where by it will be shown only on mobile version of the website
3. The message can also be set to be shown on both forms (regular and mobile) of the website

I want to capture this property as a `Nullable boolean`. say X

```
 public class Message {

     public bool? X {get;set;}

     public bool IsMobileMessage { get {return X.HasValue ? !X.Value : true } }

     public bool IsWebMessage {get {return X.HasValue ? X.Value : true} }

   }
```

- What would be the most readable name for the property?
- Should this tri-state be captured with a `Enum` instead of a `nullable boolean`?

  - A `Nullable boolean` seemed to be more attractive to me as there will no further additions to the state of the property.

Comment: I think `enum Bool { True, False, FileNotFound };` is the common pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should this tri-state be captured with a Enum instead of a nullable
>   boolean?

Absolutely, this would be self-documenting and much easier to maintain - go with an enum. Your current code is confusing at best, just looking at it I have a hard time understanding the logic - I wouldn't look forward to maintain that code - conventionally a nullable bool would be used to capture true, false and *the absence of a value* as third state. Re-interpreting the value absence (`null`) to mean something different is only inviting trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Since the third state is that both conditions are true, you really have two booleans.  Of course, that means that there are four states, and one of the states is invalid, but even so, I would use a Flags enum:

```
[Flags]
enum MessageType
{
    Web = 1,
    Mobile = 2,
    Both = Web | Mobile
}
```

If you're concerned about the size of your objects, you can declare the underlying type to be byte, and then this will actually be smaller than a bool?, which is two bytes.